# Ubuntu Installation over windows 7

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I am trying to install new Ubuntu version 18.04.3 on my window 7. After i have made a setup in USB its running fine on USB but when i try to install it on my system after successful installation and restart it still asks for Ubuntu installation option and when i remove USB it is not working properly. I have used 'something else' option and made new partitions so no old data or Windows on the PC left. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Its working fine now so far. What i am doing wrong was not selecting HDD as first option after restarting system. I should make Hard Drive option as first one instead USB Drive.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the replies. It’s working fine now so far. What I was doing wrong was not selecting HDD as the first option after restarting the system. I had to make the Hard Drive option as the first one instead of USB Drive.